# Code driven UITableView not delegating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I am adding dynamically via a initWithFrame.

```
- (void)twitterUpdate {
twitterTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 100, 420, 750)];
twitterTable.delegate = self;
twitterTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
twitterTable.separatorColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
twitterTable.dataSource = self;
[twitterView addSubview:twitterTable];
}
```

Unfortunately,

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

is not being called though I have

```
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

defined in my header.

Any ideas as to why this is not called? twitterUpdate is being called via

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(twitterUpdate) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and is drawing the table to the page. I also have

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

returning a valid NSInteger.

Are you not able to dynamically create tables like this?

Comment: You say numberOfRowsInSection is returning a valid NSInteger... is it greater than 0?

Comment: Yes. I have even tried manually setting it.

Comment: Are you really 100 % sure that numberOfSectionsInTableView: returns value > 0 and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: returns value > 0 for particular sections? Because you can add UITableView in this way without problems.

Comment: And you get the same results if you call [twitterTable reloadData]?

Comment: Awesome @MarkPowell. That did it! Thank you! Please post as an answer and I will set it.

Comment: Is numberOfRowsInSection definitely being called?

Comment: @JohnSloan Great, made it the answer.

Comment: If you're just calling `twitterUpdate`, why are you using `performSelector:withObject:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you call:

```
[twitterTable reloadData];
```